# loading javascript files issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I am experiencing some issue with javascript loading. Using the `jquery file upload`, I have to load a bunch of files (containing a file `http://site/somefile.js`) that all seem to be correctly called. But when the page is loaded and when I import some file using an input file tag, I have to add `$.getScript('http://site/somefile.js')` to make the file import correct. How can it be ?
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the jquery file upload plugin from https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload, then I experienced some similar issue. I fixed it adding the target id `#fileupload` in the `form` tag rather that in the `input` file tag

Answer (score 0):

> Well, if you insert a `JavaScript` file into a `<input type="file">` then the javascript is not going to be **executed**, that would make no sense.
>
> Why would you wan't to do this?

You could however,

```
$('#fileInput').on('change', function() {
    $.getScript( this.value );
});
```

But note this won't work with `file://` addresses.